# How to inject data into a graph when using an input pipeline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using an initializable iterator in my code. The iterator returns batches of size 100 from a csv dataset that has 20.000 entries. During training, however, I came across a problem. Consider this piece of code:

```
def get_dataset_iterator(batch_size): 

    # parametrized with batch_size
    dataset = ... 
    return dataset.make_initializable_iterator()


## build a model and train it (x is the input of my model)
iterator = get_dataset_iterator(100)
x = iterator.get_next()
y = model(x)

## L1 norm as loss, this works because the model is an autoencoder
loss = tf.abs(x - y)

## training operator
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    for epoch in range(100):

        sess.run(iterator.initializer)

        # iterate through the whole dataset once during the epoch and 
        # do 200 mini batch updates

        for _ in range(number_of_samples // batch_size):
            sess.run(train_op)

        print(f'Epoch {epoch} training done!')

        # TODO: print loss after epoch here
```

I am interested in the training loss AFTER finishing the epoch. It makes most sense to me that I calculate the average loss over the whole training set (e.g. feeding all 20.000 samples through the network and averaging their loss). I could reuse the dataset iterator here with a batch size of 20.000, but I have declared x as the input.

So the questions are:

1.) Does the loss calculation over all 20.000 examples make sense? I have seen some people do the calculation with just a mini-batch (the last batch of the epoch).

2.) How can I calculate the loss over the whole training set with an input pipeline? I have to inject all of training data somehow, so that I can run `sess.run(loss)` without calculating it over only 100 samples (because x is declared as input).

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:**

If I wrote my training loop the following way, there would be some things that bother me:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    for epoch in range(100):

        sess.run(iterator.initializer)

        # iterate through the whole dataset once during the epoch and 
        # do 200 mini batch updates

        for _ in range(number_of_samples // batch_size):
            _, current_loss = sess.run([train_op, loss])

        print(f'Epoch {epoch} training done!')
        print(current_loss)
```

Firstly, loss would still be evaluated before doing the last weight update. That means whatever comes out is not the latest value. Secondly, I would not be able to access `current_loss` after exiting the for loop so I would not be able to print it.

Answer (score 1):

1) Loss calculation over the whole training set (before updating weights) does make sense and is called batch gradient descent (despite using the whole training set and not a mini batch).

However, calculating a loss for your whole dataset before updating weights is slow (especially with large datasets) and training will take a long time to converge. As a result, using a mini batch of data to calculate loss and update weights is what is normally done instead. Although using a mini batch will produce a noisy estimate of the loss it is actually good enough estimate to train networks with enough training iterations.

**EDIT:**

I agree that the loss value you print will not be the latest loss with the latest updated weights. Probably for most cases it really doesn't make much different or change results so people just go with how you have wrote the code above. However, if you really want to obtain the true latest loss value after you have done training (to print out) then you will just have to run the loss op again after you have done a train op e.g.:

```
for _ in range(number_of_samples // batch_size):
            sess.run([train_op])
            current_loss = sess.run([loss])
```

This will get your true latest value. Of course this wont be on the whole dataset and will be just for a minibatch of 100. Again the value is likely a good enough estimate but if you wish to calculate exact loss for whole dataset you will have to run through your entire set e.g. another loop and then average the loss:

```
    ...
    # Train loop
    for _ in range(number_of_samples // batch_size):
        _, current_loss = sess.run([train_op, loss])

    print(f'Epoch {epoch} training done!')

    # Calculate loss of whole train set after training an epoch.
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    current_loss_list = []
    for _ in range(number_of_samples // batch_size):
            _, current_loss = sess.run([loss])
            current_loss_list.append(current_loss)
    train_loss_whole_dataset = np.mean(current_loss_list)
    print(train_loss_whole_dataset)
```

**EDIT 2:**
As pointed out doing the serial calls to train_op then loss will call the iterator twice and so things might not work out nicely (e.g. run out of data). Therefore my 2nd bit of code will be better to use.

Comment: Regarding 1.): unfortunately, it is not obvious to me why it makes sense to calculate the loss before the weight update (e.g. the train_op here) because I want to know the newer loss value and not what it was before. What am I missing here? And regarding 2.): this way I hoped to get the whole dataset in one batch and use it to calculate the loss over all samples.

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you are asking now, updating answer.

Comment: Thank you, but the issue with the serial eval of ``train_op`` and ``loss`` that both need x. Here it means that the ``get_next()`` method is called twice and the loop actually fails with an ``OutOfRangeException``. That is because the calculated number of mini batch updates is 20000/100 = 200, but I only get to iteration 100. That is what makes input pipelines so tricky to handle for me. It would be great if you could save the return value of `get_next` once and reuse it. I will however test your second solution.

Comment: Yes thats a good point it will call get_next() again so you will run out of data and things wont work nicely. 

Probably my second way is better then and you will have to re-initialise the dataset before looping for loss calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code will answer your questions:
(A) how can you print the batch loss AFTER performing the train step? (B) how can you calculate the loss over the entire training set, even though the dataset iterator gives only a batch each time?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dataset_size = 200
batch_size= 5
dimension = 4

# create some training dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.\
    from_tensor_slices(np.random.normal(2.0,size=(dataset_size,dimension)).
    astype(np.float32))

dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size) # take batches

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
x = tf.cast(iterator.get_next(),tf.float32)
w = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(size=(1,dimension)).astype(np.float32))

loss_func = lambda x,w: tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(x-w)) # notice that the loss function is a mean!
loss = loss_func(x,w) # this is the loss that will be minimized
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

# we are going to use control_dependencies so that we know that we have a loss calculation AFTER the train step
with tf.control_dependencies([train_op]):
    loss_after_train_op = loss_func(x,w) # this is an identical loss, but will only be calculated AFTER train_op has
                                         # been performed

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # train one epoch
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    for i in range(dataset_size//batch_size):
        # the training step will update the weights based on ONE batch of examples each step
       loss1,_,loss2 = sess.run([loss,train_op,loss_after_train_op])
       print('train step {:d}.  batch loss before step: {:f}.  batch loss after step: {:f}'.format(i,loss1,loss2))

    # evaluate loss on entire training set. Notice that this calculation assumes the the loss is of the form 
    # tf.reduce_mean(...)
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    epoch_loss = 0
    for i in range(dataset_size // batch_size):
        batch_loss = sess.run(loss)
        epoch_loss += batch_loss*batch_size
    epoch_loss = epoch_loss/dataset_size
    print('loss over entire training dataset: {:f}'.format(epoch_loss))
```

As for your question whether it makes sense to calculate loss over the entire training set - yes, it makes sense, for evaluation purposes. It usually does not make sense to perform training steps which are based on all of the training set since this set is usually very large and you want to update your weights more often, without needing to go over the entire training set each time.

Comment: This is a good answer, I wasn't aware of the existence of `control_dependencies`. While your example works flawlessly, I have difficulties to make it work for my code (loss before and after appear to be the same all the time). Nevertheless, I will take two things from this: Firstly, using the batch loss as an estimate of the dataset loss is common practice (even though it is not even the loss after the last batch). And secondly, it is possible to get the loss after the last batch, but it is not commonly put in practice. Is this correct?

Comment: Also regarding my second question: is there a possibility in TensorFlow to inject data into this graph during training? You avoided this by summing up the batch results in your answer. I looking for something like instead of using batches from the dataset as x for my model, inject values from a variable y into it.

Comment: notice that there are two reasons that you may want to calculate the loss function: (1) for evaluation purposes, to see whether the loss is small enough and whether the training is still decreasing it etc. (2) for gradient calculation, and then you use this gradient to update the weights (gradient descent).

Comment: for option (2), you usually calculate the loss only on a small batch. This means that your calculation is just an estimate, but the estimate is usually accurate enough (if batch size is not too small) so that the learning proceeds in reasonable speed. Using the entire training dataset in (2) usually makes training much longer, because it takes a long time to calculate the loss before each weight update.

Comment: for option (1), if you are interested in the loss over all the training dataset, that's fine, but make sure do this evaluation step only once in a while (for example, once every few epoch), since this evaluation takes quite a long time (and you usually also want to perform evaluation on a validation test, which also takes time).

Comment: "is there a possibility in TensorFlow to inject data into this graph during training?" - I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean the following?: take a batch of `x` values from the dataset, and calculate `y`. Then, for a future batch, take for the `x` values the previously calculated `y` values.